# cannot open .ipynb file even if ipython and jupyter is installed in my pc

Tags: ipython, jupyter

I have installed ipython, jupyter etc using pip in my windows 7 pc. Now I want to open a .pynb file from command line. When I typed 'jupyter notebook' it is showing: 'jupyter' is not a recognized internal or external command ......   Can you tell where is the problem? Can't I open the file from command line or I have to install an IDE like 'pycharm' or 'anaconda'?

Answer (score 1):

Please try the below command:

```
python -m notebook
```

This should work without anaconda.

Comment: It worked for me, thank you :) Do you know the reason? I'm working in a conda environment and before I did not have any issues, but when today I tried, it didn't work...